# A issue with the javascript event Object

Tags: javascript

I am teaching myself JavaScript and to improve my programming logic I decided to make a Hangman game. Everything works but I am having a problem with the win or lose function. The logic is If the indexCompare array length is === to correctGuesses Array length. Display You win If your lives are === to 0 Display you lose. But for some reason when a correct guess is pushed to the correctGuesses Array if it is a letter that appears more then once in the word. Only 1 occurrence of that letter is added to the array. So certain words never result in a win. And the win condition is never fulfilled. And I think it has something to do with me getting the value from the event Object. I might be wrong though. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```js
var gameCore = window.onload = function() {
  var hangmanWords = ["super", "venus", "spanish", "darkness", "tenebris", "meatball", "human", "omega", "alpha", "isochronism", "supercalifragilisticexpialidocious"];
  var commentsArray = ["I belive in you! You can do the thing!", "There is still hope keep trying", "Third times a charm", "You can do this", "Think player think! The counter is almost out", "Never give up", "The last melon 0.0", "What the frog you had one job u_u"];
  var hints = ["The opposite of ordinary.", "A planet in are solar system.", "One of the largest languages in the world", "The opposite of light", "A rare word for darkness", "A tasty kind of sphear AKA 'ball' ", "You are A?", "A letter in the greek alphabet.", "Another letter in the greek alphabet.", "A word about time that almost no one uses.", "A big word that you know if you have seen mary poppins but never use."]
  var correctGuesses = [];
  var lives = 7;
  var indexCompare = [];
  var choosenWord = []
  var arrayCounter = [];
  //get elements
  var showHint = document.getElementById("hint");
  var showLivesLeft = document.getElementById("lives");
  var showComments = document.getElementById("comment");
  var showLoseOrWin = document.getElementById("winOrLoseDisplay");
  // click assigner function
  var clickAssigner = function(event) {
    var letterHandler = document.getElementsByClassName("letters");
    for (var i = 0; i < letterHandler.length; i++) {
      letterHandler[i].addEventListener("click", compare, false);
    }
    var hintHandler = document.getElementById("hint");
    hintHandler.addEventListener("click", hint, false);
  }
  clickAssigner(event);

  function hint(event) {
    if (arrayCounter[0] === 0) {
      showHint.innerHTML = hints[arrayCounter]
    };
    if (arrayCounter[0] === 1) {
      showHint.innerHTML = hints[arrayCounter]
    };
    if (arrayCounter[0] === 2) {
      showHint.innerHTML = hints[arrayCounter]
    };
    if (arrayCounter[0] === 3) {
      showHint.innerHTML = hints[arrayCounter]
    };
    if (arrayCounter[0] === 4) {
      showHint.innerHTML = hints[arrayCounter]
    };
    if (arrayCounter[0] === 5) {
      showHint.innerHTML = hints[arrayCounter]
    };
    if (arrayCounter[0] === 6) {
      showHint.innerHTML = hints[arrayCounter]
    };
    if (arrayCounter[0] === 7) {
      showHint.innerHTML = hints[arrayCounter]
    };
    if (arrayCounter[0] === 8) {
      showHint.innerHTML = hints[arrayCounter]
    };
    if (arrayCounter[0] === 9) {
      showHint.innerHTML = hints[arrayCounter]
    };
    if (arrayCounter[0] === 10) {
      showHint.innerHTML = hints[arrayCounter]
    };
  }
  // word selector and display function
  // arrayCounter is the same as i 
  function wordSelector() {
    var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * (10 - 0 + 1)) + 0;
    arrayCounter.push(randomNumber);
    var livesContainer = document.createElement("p");
    var livesNumber = lives;
    showLivesLeft.setAttribute("id", "livesNumbers");
    showLivesLeft.appendChild(livesContainer);
    livesContainer.innerHTML = livesNumber;
    var selectedWord = hangmanWords[arrayCounter];
    var wordDisplay = document.getElementById("wordDisplay");
    var correctWordDisplay = document.createElement("ul");
    var playerGuess;

    for (var i = 0; i < selectedWord.length; i++) {
      correctWordDisplay.setAttribute("id", "correctWordDisplay-UL");
      playerGuess = document.createElement("li");
      playerGuess.setAttribute("class", "playerGuess");
      playerGuess.innerHTML = "_";

      indexCompare.push(playerGuess);
      wordDisplay.appendChild(correctWordDisplay);
      correctWordDisplay.appendChild(playerGuess);
    }
  }
  wordSelector();
  // compare function // decrement lives function // remove health bar
  function compare(event) {
    var livesDisplay = document.getElementById("livesNumbers");
    var btnVal = event.target.value;
    var word = hangmanWords[arrayCounter];
    for (var i = 0; i < word.length; i++) {
      if (word[i] === btnVal) {
        indexCompare[i].innerHTML = btnVal;
      }
    }
    var c = word.indexOf(btnVal);
    if (c === -1) {
      event.target.removeAttribute("letters");
      event.target.setAttribute("class", "incorrectLetter");
      event.target.removeEventListener("click", compare);
      lives -= 1;
      livesDisplay.innerHTML = lives;
    } else {
      event.target.removeAttribute("letters");
      event.target.setAttribute("class", "correctLetter");
      event.target.removeEventListener("click", compare);
      correctGuesses.push(event.target.value);
    }
    comments();
    winOrLose();
    // console.log(event);
    // console.log(word);
  }
  // comment function
  function comments() {
    if (lives === 7) {
      showComments.innerHTML = "<p>" + commentsArray[0] + "</p>"
    };
    if (lives === 6) {
      showComments.innerHTML = "<p>" + commentsArray[1] + "</p>"
    };
    if (lives === 5) {
      showComments.innerHTML = "<p>" + commentsArray[2] + "</p>"
    };
    if (lives === 4) {
      showComments.innerHTML = "<p>" + commentsArray[3] + "</p>"
    };
    if (lives === 3) {
      showComments.innerHTML = "<p>" + commentsArray[4] + "</p>"
    };
    if (lives === 2) {
      showComments.innerHTML = "<p>" + commentsArray[5] + "</p>"
    };
    if (lives === 1) {
      showComments.innerHTML = "<p>" + commentsArray[6] + "</p>"
    };
    if (lives === 0) {
      showComments.innerHTML = "<p>" + commentsArray[7] + "</p>"
    };
  }
  // win or lose function
  function winOrLose() {
    for (var i = 0; i < indexCompare.length; i++) {
      if (indexCompare.length === correctGuesses.length) {
        showLoseOrWin.innerHTML = "<p>" + "YOU WIN!!! :D" + "</p>";
      }
    }
    if (lives === 0) {
      showLoseOrWin.innerHTML = "<p>" + "YOU LOSE u_u" + "</p>";
    }
  }

  function reset() {

  }

}
```

```css
html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}


/* http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/ 
            v2.0 | 20110126
            License: none (public domain)
            */

html,body,div,span,applet,object,iframe,h1,h2,
h3,h4,h5,h6,p,blockquote,pre,a,abbr,acronym,address,big,cite,code,del,dfn,em,
img,ins,kbd,q,
s,samp,small,strike,strong,sub,sup,tt,var,b,u,
i,center,dl,dt,dd,ol,ul,li,fieldset,form,label,
legend,table,caption,tbody,tfoot,thead,tr,th,
td,article,aside,canvas,details,embed,figure,figcaption,
footer,header,hgroup,menu,nav,output,ruby,section,
summary,time,mark,audio,video {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  font-size: 100%;
  font: inherit;
  vertical-align: baseline;
}


/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */

article,aside,details,figcaption,figure,footer,header,hgroup,menu,nav,section {
  display: block;
}

body {
  line-height: 1;
}

ol,ul {
  list-style: none;
}

blockquote,
q {
  quotes: none;
}

blockquote:before,
blockquote:after,
q:before,
q:after {
  content: '';
  content: none;
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0;
}

#container {
  overflow: hidden;
  max-width: 60%;
  background-color: yellowgreen;
  margin: 7em auto;
  padding: 1em;
}

#wordDisplay {
  height: 6em;
  background-color: orangered;
  margin-bottom: 0.2em;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 2.4em;
  font-size: 26px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

#correctWordDisplay-UL {
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.playerGuess {
  margin: 0em 0.08em;
  font-size: 30px;
}

#hint {
  max-width: 26em;
  padding: 1em;
  background-color: skyblue;
  border: 0.5em ridge gold;
  font-weight: 900;
  margin: 0em auto 1em auto;
  text-align: center;
}

#hint:hover {
  background-color: coral;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-style: oblique;
}

#letterDiplay {
  width: 14em;
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
  background: crimson;
  padding: 1em;
}

.letters {
  margin: 0.3em auto;
  text-align: center;
  width: 4em;
  height: 3em;
  font-weight: 900;
  background-color: darkorange;
  border: 3px ridge darkblue;
}

.letters:hover {
  background: steelblue;
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#theChanceCounter {
  text-align: center;
  float: right;
  width: 14em;
  background-color: crimson;
  height: 28.9em;
}


/* #lives{
            width: 3em;
            height: 3em;
            margin: 1em auto 0em auto;
            background-color: teal;
            color: black;
            font-weight: 900;
            text-align: center;
            } */

#livesNumbers {
  margin-top: 1em;
  border: 3px solid black;
  width: 3em;
  height: 3em;
  padding: 0.9em 0em 0em 0em;
  margin: 1em auto 0em auto;
  background-color: teal;
  color: black;
  font-weight: 900;
  text-align: center;
}

.correctLetter {
  margin: 0.3em auto;
  text-align: center;
  width: 4em;
  height: 3em;
  font-weight: 900;
  background: green;
  color: yellow;
}

.incorrectLetter {
  margin: 0.3em auto;
  text-align: center;
  width: 4em;
  height: 3em;
  font-weight: 900;
  background: red;
  color: yellow;
}

#comment {
  background-color: forestgreen;
  width: 12em;
  height: 4em;
  padding: 1em 0.4em 0em 0.4em;
  margin: 0.3em auto 0.3em auto;
  border: 3px solid black;
}

#winOrLoseDisplay {
  width: 18em;
  padding: 1em;
  background-color: skyblue;
  border: 0.5em ridge orange;
  font-weight: 900;
  margin: 0em auto 1em 1.4em;
  text-align: center;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <section id="wordDisplay">

  </section>
  <section id="hint">Click for hint.</section>
  <section id="letterDiplay">
    <button class="letters" value="a">A</button>
    <button class="letters" value="b">B</button>
    <button class="letters" value="c">C</button>
    <button class="letters" value="d">D</button>
    <button class="letters" value="e">E</button>
    <button class="letters" value="f">F</button>
    <button class="letters" value="g">G</button>
    <button class="letters" value="h">H</button>
    <button class="letters" value="i">I</button>
    <button class="letters" value="j">J</button>
    <button class="letters" value="k">K</button>
    <button class="letters" value="l">L</button>
    <button class="letters" value="m">M</button>
    <button class="letters" value="n">N</button>
    <button class="letters" value="o">O</button>
    <button class="letters" value="p">P</button>
    <button class="letters" value="q">Q</button>
    <button class="letters" value="r">R</button>
    <button class="letters" value="s">S</button>
    <button class="letters" value="t">T</button>
    <button class="letters" value="u">U</button>
    <button class="letters" value="v">V</button>
    <button class="letters" value="w">W</button>
    <button class="letters" value="x">X</button>
    <button class="letters" value="y">Y</button>
    <button class="letters" value="z">Z</button>
  </section>
  <section id="winOrLoseDisplay"></section>
  <section id="theChanceCounter">
    <div id="lives">

    </div>
    <div id="comment">

    </div>
  </section>
</div>

</script>
```

Comment: The demo has an error btw :)

Comment: Where is the error?

Comment: I meant if i click on "run code snippet" it throws an error

Comment: Ohh I was not getting that error hmm  guacward 0.0